# Why doesn't urllib2 throw a 404?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, urllib2

I have a public folder in Google Drive, in which I store pictures.

In Python, I am trying to detect if a picture with a particular name exist or not. I am using this code:

```
import urllib2
url = "http://googledrive.com/host/0B7K23HtYjKyBfnhYbkVyUld3YUVqSWgzWm1uMXdrMzQ0NlEwOXVUd3o0MWVYQ1ZVMlFSNms/0000.png"
resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print resp.getcode()
```

And even though there is no file with this name in this folder, this code is not throwing an exception and is printing "200" as the return code. I have checked in my browser and this URL (http://googledrive.com/host/0B7K23HtYjKyBfnhYbkVyUld3YUVqSWgzWm1uMXdrMzQ0NlEwOXVUd3o0MWVYQ1ZVMlFSNms/0000.png) does return a 404, after a few redirects.

Why doesn't urllib2 detect that this file actually doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the request, your request goes to google's web servers and is processed there. If and only if google's servers were to return a 404, would you see a 404 on your end; urllub2 simply encapsulates the underlying handshaking and data transfer logic.

In this particular case, google's server side code requires the request to be authenticated, and your request url is simply unauthenticated. As such, the request is redirected to the login page, and since this is a valid existing page/response, urllib2 shows the correct code 200. You can [get the same page](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https://drive.google.com/st/auth/host/0B7K23HtYjKyBfnhYbkVyUld3YUVqSWgzWm1uMXdrMzQ0NlEwOXVUd3o0MWVYQ1ZVMlFSNms/0000.png) if you [open the link in a private window](http://googledrive.com/host/0B7K23HtYjKyBfnhYbkVyUld3YUVqSWgzWm1uMXdrMzQ0NlEwOXVUd3o0MWVYQ1ZVMlFSNms/0000.png).

However, if you are authenticated and then open the url (basically logged into your gmail/googgle docs account), you would get the 404 error.